# Unable to receive array in PHP post method

Tags: php, jquery

I have to POST selected input checkboxes using jquery to PHP. I inserted the array to an hidden input field. When I receive the array in PHP, only one userid is deleted. But I want all the selected userid to be deleted from the database.

My jquery code is:

```
$("#delSelected").click(function(){
        var checks = [];
        $.each($("#userList input:checked"), function(){            
            checks.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("#modal-user").html("Selected Users");
        $("#modal-footer").html("<form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='checkboxes[]' value='"+ checks +"'><button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' type='submit' name='submit'>Yes Delete</button></form><button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>");
    });
```

My PHP code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxes'];
     foreach($checkboxes as $uId){
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$uId' ");
     }
}
```

Comment: have you got all user id in `$uId` this variable in checkbox loop?

Comment: yes when I print $uId within foreach loop its outputing like : 32,44,56

Comment: okay, so please double check with the table name and column name or try to delete with `in` query also debug with print query in  loop and execute on mysql

Comment: So, your $checkboxes reads "2,4,5,6", then what does the SQL look like? `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '2,4,5,6'`. And? Is this a valid SQL syntax?

Comment: No, that's not the valid syntax. That's the problem I am facing. I am expecting, from each loop:  DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 2; then DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 4 and so on

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: Try convert JSON to String in JS `checks  = JSON.stringify(checks)` in and get it back in PHP `$checkboxes  = json_decode($checkboxes)`.

Comment: Also echo `$checkboxes` before decode it to see what it looks?

Comment: before decoding, ["51","50","34"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the array index.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxes'];
     foreach($checkboxes[0] as $uId){
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$uId' ");
     }
}
```

Comment: @Rishi what is your print_r($checkboxes); result?

Comment: before doing explode: -  Array ( [0] => 50,34 )

Comment: @Rishi then please try with this `$checkboxesArray = explode(',', $checkboxes[0]);` answer updated

Comment: Fine I'm happy that I can help